# Exchange rate of limit orders with a positive interval

Tags: exchanges, exchange-order

Consider some exchange, e.g. Mt. Gox, with just two users, Alice and Bob. If Alice places a sale order limited above 90$, and Bob places a buy order limited below 110$, at what rate will the exchange take place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on who posts the order first.

If Alice posts first a `sell` at 90, then Bob posts a `buy` at 110, Bob will `buy` from Alice at 90, and any excess will be posted as a `buy` at 110 (if he wanted to buy more than Alice sold).

If Bob posted first a `buy` at 110, then Alice posted a `sell` at 90, the opposite would happen: Alice would `sell` to Bob at 110, and any excess would be posted as a `sell` at 90 (if she wanted to sell more than Bob wanted to buy).

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to a reference as well?

Comment: @stanga there are plenty of resources explaining limit orders, but they don't address it _exactly_ your question, since they take it for granted. Wasn't able to find you one, sorry.